# ZFS stangre thing with unavaible pool

Tags: zfsonlinux

I have an old debian with ZFS 0.6.3 ( as far as I remember ) under the installed OS half of my pool is in "UNAVAILABLE" state.

I try to explore more with FreeBSD live CD and Debian ZFS rescue disc

And my pool seem OK ! I can mount partition and read files and directories

When I reboot on the native OS ... pool is "UNAVAILABLE" again !
A new boot on live CD show usable pool !!!

Now I made a scrub of pool ... but I don't understand what's happend !

Any advice ?

Best Regards

Comment: What does `zpool status` show?

Comment: Does the OS see all the drives that are members of the pool?  Look at the output of `lsblk` and so on.

Comment: Hello  Zpool status says the half of my disks are unavailable  ( around 20 disks  of 40 ) ...   lsblk see all disk :( ... the PERC didn't complain ... it's very strange. At this time , tje liveCD is scrubbing .. .and didn't complain too !   ... but very long :) 65 hours to finish the "scrub"  ... what was very strange is that my pool is readable from liveCD ... Best regards